# Prove a sequence is bounded

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I had to do the next exercise to complete a proof in my calculus class:

> If $y_n\to x\neq 0$ and $y_n\neq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\left(\frac{1}{xy_n}\right)$ is bounded.

I proved that $\left(\frac{1}{xy_n}\right)$ converges. Since every convergent sequence is bounded, then $\left(\frac{1}{xy_n}\right)$ is bounded. Is there a way to directly prove that $\left(\frac{1}{xy_n}\right)$ is bounded? I haven't been able to do so.

Comment: By convergence $|y_n|$ is bounded below. Therefore $\left(\dfrac 1 {|xy_n|}\right)$ is bounded above by $\dfrac 1 {|x| \inf |y_n|}$ and thus $\left(\dfrac 1 {xy_n}\right)$ is bounded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x>0$. There exists $n_0$ such that  $y_n >\frac   x 2$ for $n \geq n_0$ ( $|y_n-x| <\frac  x 2$ implies $y_n >\frac x  2$). Hence $ 0 < \frac 1 {y_n x} < \frac 2 {x^{2}}$ for $n \geq n_0$. Let $M$ be the maximum of $\frac 2 {x^{2}}$ and the numbers $|\frac 1 {y_n x}|, n <n_0$. Then the sequence is bounded by $M$ in absolute value . The case $x <0$ is similar.

Answer (score 1):

As $y_n$ converges to $x$, use $\epsilon=\frac{|x|}2$, and you can find an $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, $|y_n-x|<\frac{|x|}2$ and $\left|\frac1{y_n}\right|<\frac2{|x|}$.